# What is your favorite haggadah?

Tags: passover, books-generally, passover-seder-hagada, product-recommendation

There are many classic and modern haggadot. Any recommendations? If so, why? And if available online (such as at HebrewBooks), please provide a link.

Comment: Should we close this as "subjective"? I had a similar idea last year and asked it in a more objective fashion: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/569/how-do-you-pick-a-hagada-to-use-at-the-seder

Comment: Close it as redundant to the other, at least.

Comment: If it's acceptable despite subjectivity, then it's not redundant. The other question asked for guidelines, while this one asks for specific recommendations.

Comment: Perhaps a way to make this one more objective would be to reframe it as "I'd like a Hagada [that facilitates a Seder] with the following characteristics: ... Which would you recommend, and why?"

Comment: Isaac, I think it's asking for recommendations, and I think this is a useful post. I like it as a slightly easier-to-relate version of the one you posted. Not everyone looks at the search for a Haggadah itself as a topic for intellectual discourse. Also, the ones listed below are not the same as those listed in answer to last year's question. Please keep it open.

Comment: I also want to answer it - very subjectively - once I get home to look at my collection. I have a couple of obscure ones that I like purely for their obscurity.

Comment: @R'Isaac Moses, re your reply to my comment: It's redundant precisely to the extent that it's not subjective: It's the subjective counterpart to the other question.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Many answers and a +4 rating...Re-open!

Answer (score 2):

Maxwell House - good to the last drop

Answer (score 2):

1) Favorite to use 
YU Hagaddah - Hebrew by Koren

2) Favorite to learn 
Hagaddah of Gr"a

3) Favorite High-end
Moss Hagaddah

Answer (score 2):

Abarbanel's haggada is a classic. I find myself in awe of it every year over again.

(Mosad R' Kook recently [reprinted it](http://www.zbermanbooks.com/Page.asp?ID=913866aaca735b055c48328a6c1074c7d146d2af85ba1e45c7fcf415dfe230e1&ProductID=136272), but the old print is on [hebrewbooks](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/11067).)

Answer (score 2):

The [Hirsch Haggadah](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0873064615) is excellent, and unusual in that it contains extensive commentary to parts of the haggadah that often get short shrift, such as kiddush and birkas hamazon.

Answer (score 2):

*[Haggadah Migdal Eider](http://hebrewbooks.org/10883)* is a great and classic all rounder.

Comment: this one?
http://hebrewbooks.org/10883

is that because of the plethora of perushim (150)?

Comment: It's not really a plethora of perushim. It's just a collection of comments and ideas from a plethora of perushim. They are all highly abridged. Still, I have one and I like using it at the seder, since I can glance at quick snippets from a wide variety of sources.

Comment: yaavetz, exactly my reason.